# Work with default routes but custom routes give uninitialized constant Api::V1::UserController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I know this questions is asked several times but I checked those answers but nothing seems to fix my issue.

**users_controller.rb** on path app/controllers/api/v1/

```
module Api
    module V1
        class UsersController < ApplicationController

            def create_user
                @users = User.new(user_params)
                if @users.save
                    render json: { status: '201', message: 'User created successfully' }
                else
                    render json: { status: '400', message: 'Invalid user info', data: @users.errors }
                end
            end

            def user_params
                params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
namespace 'api' do
        namespace 'v1' do

          post "user/createuser", to: "user#create_user"
        end
end
```

What I have tried:

- Checked the directory structure it is as mentioned
- Restarted the server and checked
- Folder name: all simple controllers > api > v1

But this works fine when I changed the routes.rb

`post "user/createuser", to: "user#create_user"`

to `resource :users`

and

```
def create_user
```

to `def create`

**Why things does not work when I define custom routes instead of using default routes? How to get this work with custom routes**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to Rails conventions I believe you need to update your route with

```
post "user/createuser", to: "users#create"
```

instead of

```
post "user/createuser", to: "user#create_user"
```

Comment: Thank you very much my friend. It worked. I was spent close to 5 hours trying to do this. Oh just a simple 's' made a big difference.

Comment: You're welcome. I personally also do those things occasionally (I mean spending a lot of time on some silly problem :D)